# Calculating new percentages over total in a "select distinct" query with multiple percentages rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title may be puzzling, but the situation should be really simple foranyone reading the following lines.

I have this table **VAL**:

```
customer month_1 month_2 month_3 value
ABC        0.5     0      0.50    200
ABC       0.25     0.25   0.50    200
XYZ          1     0         0    150
RST          0     0         1    200
RST          0     0.50   0.50    130
```

(This is the code to get it)

```
create table VAL (customer nvarchar(255), month_1 decimal(18,2), month_2 decimal(18,2), month_3 decimal(18,2), value decimal(18,2))
insert into VAL values ('ABC',  0.5,     0  ,    0.50,    200)
insert into VAL values ('ABC',0.25 ,    0.25,   0.50 ,   200 )
insert into VAL values ('XYZ',   1 ,    0   ,      0 ,   150 )
insert into VAL values ('RST',   0 ,    0   ,      1 ,   200 )
insert into VAL values ('RST',   0 ,    0.50,   0.50 ,   130 )
```

This can be seen (transforming what is a percentage in actual values) as

```
customer value_month_1 value_month_2 value_month_3 value
ABC         100              0             100      200
ABC          50             50             100      200
XYZ         150              0               0      150
RST           0              0             200      200
RST           0             65              65      130
```

I need to transform everything in the following table, that is sort of a collapsed version of the first one:

```
customer  month_1   month_2  month_3   value
ABC        0.375     0.125     0.50     400
XYZ          1.0         0      0.0     150
RST          0.0     0.197    0.793     330
```

So far, I'm able to do this customer by customer with the following code:

```
select distinct customer
,sum(month_1) as month_1
,sum(month_2) as month_2
,sum(month_3) as month_3
,sum(value) as value
from (
select distinct customer
,month_1 * sum(value)/(select sum(value) from VAL where customer='ABC' group by customer) as month_1
,month_2 * sum(value)/(select sum(value) from VAL where customer='ABC' group by customer) as month_2
,month_3 * sum(value)/(select sum(value) from VAL where customer='ABC' group by customer) as month_3
,sum(value) as value from VAL where customer='ABC' group by customer, month_1, month_2,month_3) as NEW
group by customer
```

that gives me the following result:

```
customer  month_1   month_2  month_3   value
ABC        0.375     0.125     0.50     400
```

I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do this, probably with some command I don't know very well how to use.
Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a weighted average:

```
select customer,
       sum(month_1 * value) / sum(value) as month_1,
       sum(month_2 * value) / sum(value) as month_2,
       sum(month_3 * value) / sum(value) as month_3,
       sum(value)
from val
group by customer;
```

Comment: it looks exactly what I need, but I've probably oversimplified the original situation, now I'm trying to understand which is the part of the code that gives the following error: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression". Thanks anyway

Comment: @MaZe . . . There is no subquery in this answer, so it cannot generate that error.  If you have *another* question, then ask it as *another* question.

Comment: yes, it's exactly what I've said: this answer actually solves the question I've asked, but on my db I've something that is too complex to replicate here with a few lines of code. I'll try to figure out how to adapt your useful answer to my situation. Thanks.